# Como destruir um jQuery.fn sempre que for chamado?

Tags: jquery

Construí um plugin usando `jQuery.fn.algumaCoisa = function(options, callback){};`, mas quando chamo várias vezes no mesmo elemento, fica multiplicando o comportamento em vez de sobrepor. Tem alguma maneira de sempre que chamar essa função ele resetar o efeito sobre o elemento?

Ao chamar no mesmo elemento ele deveria resetar o comportamento, mas os botões internos estão tendo efeito multiplicado, resumindo, não estão perdendo os efeitos atribuídos anteriormente.

```
$('div').algumaCoisa(); // usario clica em um botão e chama
$('div').algumaCoisa(); // usario clica em um botão e chama
$('div').algumaCoisa(); // usario clica em um botão e chama
```

Comment: é um tanto complicado responder esta pergunta, sem saber o que tem nessa função alguma coisa, pois pensando um um função que manipule o `dom` do elemento, com o "`reset`" saberia o que foi alterado? seria necessário criar uma variável com se fosse um log das alteracções.

Comment: Orion poderia dar mais detalhes? Pois o `.fn.`  tem a funcao apenas de percorrer os elementos selecionados com uma funcao customizada, o problema parece ser no seu function, entretanto voce pode talvez usar um atributo nos elementos pra detectar se eles foram ja setados. Vou tentar formular uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema ocorre pois os eventos são setados de forma acumulativa, para resolvermos isso vamos depender um pouco da forma que você implementou. Irei mostrar dois exemplos o com evento de `.click()` e com `.on()` que são dois manipuladores de eventos do **jQuery** disponíveis nas versões **1.7 +** .

Com uso do `.click()`:

```
jQuery.fn.algumaCoisa = function(){ 

    //ele remove todos os eventos de click antes de setar
    $(this).unbind('click');

    //seta seu evento
    $(this).click(function() {
        alert("teste1");
    });    
}
```

Com uso do `.on()`:

```
jQuery.fn.algumaCoisa = function(){ 

    //ele remove todos os eventos de click antes de setar
    $(this).unbind('click');

    //seta seu evento
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        alert("teste1");
    });    
}
```

Segue [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/qhfhLx3o/), se estiver usando alguma forma diferente de setar o evento é só falar nos comentários!

Comment: O problema é que eu achava que ao remover a função do elemento destruiria todas efeitos internos setados por essa função, resolvi chamando `unbind()` nos elementos internos antes de setar novamente.

Answer (score 1):

A funcao do `jQuery.fn` não e atribuir nada, ele apenas passar os nodes selecionados para o seu metodo customizado. Quem define se vai adicionar repetidas vezes e voce.

No caso voce pode usar o `attr()` pra detectar se o node ja recebeu o atributo (se voce for usar apenas pra nodes), recomendo que tambem verifique se o item selecionado realmente e um node, pois o `$(...)`  pode receber window e document tambem.

```
function isDOM(el) {
   return el && el instanceof HTMLElement;
}

jQuery.fn.foo = function() {
    this.each(function() {
       if (isDOM(this) && $(this).attr("data-foo") !== "true") {
           $(this).attr("data-foo", "true");

           //Algo aqui
       }
    });
};
```

Desta maneira voce pode fazer varios seletores diferentes e ele vai detectar se o elemento html ja recebeu o efeito esperado.

Se o que voce quer e remover o efeito em elementos que ja o tenham, voce pode fazer assim:

```
function aplicaEfeito(el) {
    //Aqui aplica o efeito
}

function removeEfeito(el) {
    //Aqui remove o efeito
}

function isDOM(el) {
   return el && el instanceof HTMLElement;
}

jQuery.fn.foo = function() {
    this.each(function() {
       if (isDOM(this)) {
           if ($(this).attr("data-foo") !== "true") {
               $(this).attr("data-foo", "true");
                aplicaEfeito($(this));//Aplica o efeito
           } else {
                removeEfeito($(this));//Primeiro remove o efeito
                aplicaEfeito($(this));//Aplica o efeito novamente
           }
       }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça isso:

```
delete $.fn.nomedoplugin;
```

Isso não afeta as instâncias do plugin já inicializadas.

Comment: O que eu quero na realidade é zerar os efeitos sobre o elemento quando chamar a função novamente.